# Calculating the electrical power generated from a wind turbine

Tags: power, efficient-energy-use

Heres the question:

---

A wind turbine has blades that sweep an area of 2000 m^2. It convrts the power available in the wind to electrical power with a efficiency of 50%.

What is the electrical power generated if the wind speed is 10ms^-1? (The density of air is 1.3 kgm^-3).

---

I was trying to use F = ma but we dont know the acceleration.. then I tried using P = FV but we dont know the volume.... using density = m/v to calculate mass but the question only gives the area.. not the volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the equations for your calculation (starting from energy but not force).

Wind energy (mainly kinetic energy) $$E_k=\frac12 m v^2= \frac12 (\rho V) v^2$$

Then wind power $$P=\frac {dE_k}{dt}=\frac12 (\rho \frac {dV}{dt}) v^2 =\frac12 (\rho A v) v^2=\frac12 \rho A v^3$$, which is the equation Han-Kwang showed above. Note here the velocity is the velocity component normal to the turbine.

With your number, the wind power is $1.3 \times 10^6$ watts or 1.3 megawatts. That's a lot! Even with 50% efficiency, you still have 0.65 megawatts.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to know the cross-sectional area of each of the blades, not just the area swept, along with pitch angle and other information. Additionally, one thing that is not provided is the direction of the wind. Is the wind blowing directly at the turbine, or at an angle? If the wind blows at an angle, material bending stresses must also be taken into account, since the blades' cross-sectional area changes as they bend.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeking to much behind the question. [Betz's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betz's_law) states that the theoretical limit for a wind turbine is 59% of the kinetic energy ($P=A\rho v^3/2$) of the air flowing through the swept area of the blades if the windmill hadn't been there. In your case, you have 50% rather than 59%, which is a realistic value for a modern wind turbine.